# How to add a sequence of commits to another branch?

Tags: git, branch

In git, how to apply the sequence of commits "D-E"

```
master       A-B
                \
py3-version      C-D-…-E
```

back onto master, so as to obtain

```
master       A-B - <D patch applied> - <…> - <E patch applied>
                \
py3-version      C-D-…-E
```

I want to do this because `master` is a Python 2 version, with `C` being a Python 3 version *generated automatically* (through `2to3`), that I needed to improve (`D` to `E`). Now, I would like to put back improvements `D` to `E` onto the master branch (and eventually forget about `C` and the `py3-version`, which will be regenerated from the new master branch). How can this be done?

Comment: This answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16212454/1615903

Comment: @user1615903: Perfect, indeed, thank you! I had tried `git cherry-pick <range>` with an older version of git and thought it did not work, hence the question above. Good to know it works, now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is called `cherry-picking` in git lingo, where you can import changes selectively from one branch into another:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick py3-version~10..py3-version
```

this will pick the last 10 commits from the "py3-version" branch.

In case of conflicts you are prompted to manually resolve them. Then you should continue the cherry-picking with `git cherry-pick --continue` (or `git cherry-pick --abort`, if something went wrong).

Comment: I guess you mean `git cherry-pick py3-version~2 py3-version~1`, no? I updated the question to make explicit that it is actually more general than in the case of two commits. I guess that using a range `py3-version~10..py3-version~1` is the way to go, no?

Comment: PS: with `py23-version~10` being the last *non-applied* patch.

Comment: Thank you. I added details about how to handle conflicts (`--continue`), because it can be very useful to first-time `cherry-pick`-with-conflict users.